# Play Framework - Defining my Javascript file within a function

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, getscript

I'm using the Play Framework and am trying to define a javascript file within  a function in another javascript file (the reason being that I don't want these functions to be usable outside of the container function).

So I have two javascripts files, ./public/javascripts/main.js, ./public/javascript/custom.js.

From my html pages (index.scala.html) I define this as follows:

```
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/main.js")"></script>
```

Using "@routes...." doesn't work in main.js, so I tried adding the following:

```
  $.getScript("public/javascripts/custom.js", function(){
       alert("Script loaded and executed.");
    });
```

I've tried a variety of paths but it always says it can't find it.

Any idea how to do this in Play please? Looked through as much documentation as I can and nothing is there...

Any help would be brilliant!

Thank you.

Kind Regards,

Gary Shergill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Javascript Routing mechanism. As described [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaJavascriptRouting)

Define javascriptRoutes

```
  import play.api.mvc._
  object Application extends Controller {

    def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
      import routes.javascript._
      Ok(
        Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
           javascript.Assets.at     
        )
      ).as("text/javascript")
    }
  }
```

Update your .routes file

```
   GET  /routes   controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes
```

Include it into the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes"></script>
```

And then use jsRoutes variable in your javascript:

```
$.getScript(jsRoutes.controllers.Assets.at('javascripts/custom.js').url, function(){
    alert("Script loaded and executed.");
});
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the documentation regarding this.
I need to add  the def javascriptRoutes into the Application.java, but then what do I add to the routes file for this? Or is that wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have the following declaration in your routes file:

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Then the following should work:

```
$.getScript("/assets/javascripts/custom.js", function(){
   alert("Script loaded and executed.");
});
```

Comment: This returns the following:
GET http://localhost:9000/assets/javascript/custom.js?_=1390575856602
 
404 Not Found

Comment: Which directory contains your js files? `javascript` or `javascripts`? The path returning 404 is looking in `javascript` (singular). Is that right?

Comment: Good spot... I seem to have missed out the "s" when typing it out. Thanks!

Comment: Question - In the future, is it more efficient to use "<script src="javasciript file"></script>" or to use the above method ($.getScript....)?